# Checking for a value in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray(contactsArray) with contents as below.

```
{({ContactID = ""; RecordID = 45; Number = "";},
{ContactID = 134;RecordID = 47;Number = PNAPYOEMZH;})}
```

I have an independent variable say x. I need to check whether x is equal to the ContactID in the array

Comment: Are You want  to compare ContactID with RecordID?

Comment: Then check [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:0]intValue]==x.

Comment: what's with the down voting @__@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *contactsArray = <the_array>;
int x = <the_value_to_check_against>;

[contactsArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bindings){
    return ([[obj objectForKey:@"ContactID"] intValue] == x);
}]];
```

or change the predicate to:

```
[contactsArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.ContactID == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:x]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use isEqual to check things between array data, try this

```
if([[yourArray objectAtIndex:theIndex]valueForKey:@"ContactID"] isEqualToNumber [[yourArray objectAtIndex:theIndex]valueForKey:@"RecordID"])
{
NSLog(@"the contact ID matches the Record ID");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"it doesn't match")
}
```

what happened here is the if sentences is comparing the object inside your array with the value of "ContactId" with "RecordID" at the data in the index or row "theIndex"

hope this help

edit : since you edited the question into having a variable X, you can just change the second parameter comparer to [NSNumber numberWithInt:x]

if your X is a String type, you should use .intValue

Comment: if([[yourArray objectAtIndex:theIndex]valueForKey:@"ContactID"] isEqualToNumber [NSNumber numberWithInt:x]). IS this the right syntax?

Comment: the syntax is right as far as i know it, you could try it yourself, see if there's an error in the syntax, because i type it directly in the answer box (i'm kind of not using mac right now)